# Python: How do I add files to a new directory with a time-stamp?

Tags: python, directory

Im new to python. I am trying to create a script that will add imported files to a new directory with a timestamp, as a daily backup. How do I point to the new directory as it changes name every day? Here is my script:

````
gis = GIS("https://arcgis.com", "xxx", "xxx")
items = gis.content.search(query="type:Feature Service, owner:xxx", max_items=5000,)

import datetime
import shutil
import os
now = datetime.datetime.today() 
nTime = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
source = r"C:\Users\Bruger\xxx\xxx\xxx\Backup\Backup"
dest = os.path.join(source+nTime)
if not os.path.exists(dest):
    os.makedirs(dest) #creat dest dir

source_files = os.listdir(source)
for f in source_files:
    source_file = os.path.join(source,f)
    if os.path.isfile(source_file): #check if source file is a file not dir
        shutil.move(source_file,dest) #move all only files (not include dir) to dest dir

for item in items:
    service_title = item.title
    if service_title == "Bøjninger_09_06":
        try:
            service_title = item.title
            version = "1"
            fgdb_title = service_title+version
            result = item.export(fgdb_title, "File Geodatabase")
            result.download(r"C:\Users\Bruger\xxx\xxx\xxx\Backup\?????)  **what shal I write here in order to point to the new folder?**
            result.delete()
        except:
            print("An error occurred downloading"+" "+service_title)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could try an f-string instead of a regular string, like this:

`rf"C:\Users\Bruger\xxx\xxx\xxx\Backup\{dest}"`

Comment: I used the f-string as you wrote: result.download (rf"C:\Users\Bruger\xxx\xxx\xxx\Backup\{dest}") but it throws the error "An error occurred downloading...": Did I write it correctly?

Comment: Your try/except statement prevents us to know what exception occurred. Remove it, run the script and post in the comments the error message you receive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
result.download("C:\Users\Bruger\xxx\xxx\xxx\Backup\{}".format(dest))
```